# Want to download songs to my iPhone; don't want to plug it into the computer

Tags: itunes, icloud, iphone, music

I have an up-to-date (iOS wise) iPhone 4. I downloaded two songs on my computer and now I want to get them on my phone, but my version of iTunes is outdated, and my computers slow, also I'd rather just get it through iCloud on my phone. The songs are not showing up on my phone. Is there any way to possibly 'refresh' iCloud so the songs will show up without plugging in my phone?

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn on `Automatic Downloads` in `Settings > iTunes & App Store > Automatic Downloads > Music/Apps/Books/Updates` in order to get the phone to download anything you buy on the Mac/PC automatically.  You may need to be on a WiFi network, or select the `Use Mobile Data` option if you are using cell network to download.

In addition, you can also just hop into the iTunes Store on the iPhone, search for the items and then download them manually (you won't be charged again, the *Buy* option will be replaced with an icon of a cloud with a down arrow), or check your `Purchased` tab (may be under the `More` section depending how you have it configured) to list your purchases and have the ability to just show stuff `Not on This iPhone`.

Alternatively, if you turn on `Settings > Music > Show All Music` it should show all your purchases inline in the Music App, and allow you to stream or download them at will directly from within the app, but note it will show all purchases, even that Miley Cyrus you are now embarrassed to own...